# (vb) Error "Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider" when DataBinding

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm writing a web application and this part of it takes a list of strings and DataBinds them to a asp.net repeater. Here are snippets of the area of the code that does this:

stationinstructions.aspx.vb

```
'listOfFiles is a list of strings
    Me.rptFiles.DataSource = listOfFiles
    Me.rptFiles.DataBind()
```

stationinstructions.aspx

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptFiles" runat="server">
                  <HeaderTemplate>
                       <ul>
                  </HeaderTemplate>
                  <ItemTemplate>
                              <div id="color1"><li><a href="javascript:getfile('<%# Eval("Name") %>')"><%# Eval("Name") %></a></li></div>
                              <div id="color2"><b p><%# Eval("Name") %></b></div>
                  </ItemTemplate>
                  <FooterTemplate>
                       </ul>
                  </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

I am confident that I am using the right version of .net framework in the config file. This is the exact error message I get when I go past "Me.rptFiles.DataBind()":

```
Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.]
   System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName) +1042671
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource.GetDbProviderFactory() +68
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource.GetDbProviderFactorySecure() +22
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource.CreateConnection(String connectionString) +11
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +93
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +278
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.PerformSelect() +37
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +74
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +114
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +23
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +88
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +883
```

Where should I start looking to find what is causing the error?

Comment: Are you getting this error on `stationinstructions.aspx.vb` page? Looking at the exception it looks like SQL DataProvider is missing. Do you have `DbProviderFactories` section in your web.config file? Also, which .NET Framework your website is running on?

Comment: What is the actual type of `listOfFiles`? When you say "a list of strings", do you mean an actual `List<string>` or rather some `IEnumerable<string>`?